# How to get submit button to send parameters to my endpoint in Typescript,react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm creating a form in Typescript, React that's going to set parameteres for an API.With the right parameters the api will download a file for me. I'm wondering if there is some simple way to do this?

Tried with fetch, but this shouldnt be needed when i only want to jump into the API?

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
    <MyForm onSubmit={({ email, firstName, lastName }) => {
    // I dont know what i should put here.
    }}
    />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Maybe this example can help you : [building-super-simple-react-form-component-typescript-basics](https://www.carlrippon.com/building-super-simple-react-form-component-typescript-basics/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution to fetch out the file if anyone got the same issue.

```
       fetch(url + email)
      .then(response => response.blob())

      .then(blob => URL.createObjectURL(blob))

      .then(url => {

          window.open(url, '_blank');

          URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

      });

    }
```